# How to swap left/right stereo channels for one sound device in MacOS?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, monterey

I need to swap left/right audio channels for bluetooth speakers in MacOS (Monterey, M1 iMac). I have tried swapping channels in Audio MIDI setup (as suggested, for example, [here](https://macmost.com/swap-speakers.html)), but playing stereo test videos on YouTube ignores that setting. How to swap the stereo channels in Monterey?

Comment: The Audio Midi setup page is the only built-in way to swap channels. I have no idea why it wouldn't work. That aside, have you tried the simple expedient of swapping the speaker placings?

Comment: It seems that it only doesn't work for the Bluetooth speakers (it does work for the built-in speaker). Swapping speakers physically would be my last resort option, since I would need to employ longer cables.

Comment: Another web guide with visuals for using the Audio MIDI Setup tool: http://bytesandbolts.com/swap-speaker-output-channels-in-macos

Comment: @SpinUp__ADavis This doesn't work with bluetooth speakers

Comment: @theV0ID  I understand you tried it already and it didn't solve your issue (+1 for good question), just wanted to link to the better guide for googlers that might find it useful on analog speakers (like me)

Comment: @SpinUp__ADavis your guide worked for me with a USB audio device. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It costs US $100 plus tax, it is hitting a mosquito with a sledgehammer, and Apple holds up several hoops one must jump through to get kernel extensions enabled these days…  but if all else fails and you cannot achieve this natively, I have done this in the past with third-party software: Rogue Amoeba's *[Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/)*.

Here is an example, yielding reverse stereo by just digitally crossing the wires over. The audio playing at the time of this screenshot was louder on the right, but in the bluetooth output pictured, and my ears, they've been swapped and it's louder on the left.
[image: screenshot of Rogue Amoeba app "Loopback", showing one possible routing. All audio from Safari is virtually wired L to R, and R to L, for reverse stereo sound to a subsequent bluetooth output]

Comment: I really assumed you were joking regarding the $100 USD…

Comment: Yes—unfortunate for this need. I bought Loopback to be my digital audio routing matrix; used for running events, livestreaming, music recording and monitoring, and some video production. It replaced a couple thousand dollars worth of old school, physical audio gear. Oh, and I guess it can swap stereo channels.